# Am I on the right track with this question on standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, means, variance

1. The final exam scores listed below are from one section of MATH 200.  **How many scores were within one standard deviation of the mean? How many scores were within two standard deviations of the mean?**

   99   34   86   57   73   85    91   93   46    96   88   79    68   85   89

First, calculate the mean: 
99+34+86+57+73+85+91+93+46+96+88+79+68+85+89 divided by 15
1169/15 = 77.93 or 78

Next, find the range:
 Highest minus lowest 99-34 = 65

Find the variance:
(99-78) ²+(34-78) ²+(86-78) ²+(57-78) ²+(73-78) ²+(85-78) ²+(91-78) ²+(93-78) ²+(46-78) ²+(96-78) ²+(88-78) ²+(79-78) ²+(68-78) ²+(85-78) ²+(89-78) ² divided by 15

(21) ²+(-44) ²+(8) ²+(-21) ²+(-5) ²+(7) ²+(13) ²+(15) ²+(-32) ²+(18) ²+(10) ²+(1) ²+(-10) ²+(7) ²+(11) ² divided by 15

441+1936+64+441+25+49+169+225+1024+324+100+1+100+49+121/15

5069/15 = 337.9 or 338 variance

Square the variance to get the standard deviation:  sq rt 338 = 18.38 (18 rounded)

Mean – standard deviation:
78+18= 96

Mean + standard deviation:
78-18= 60

Standard Deviation = 60 to 96
(11 scores fall in this category)
(4 scores do not fall in between those numbers)

Mean plus one standard deviation: 78 + 18  = 96

Mean plus two standard deviations: 78 + 18(2)  78 + 36  = 114 **(96 to 114)**

**I don't know how to answer those two questions based on my calculations... Did i do this equation correctly?**

Comment: For variance: You have 11 numbers. Subtract the mean from all of them and you get 11 numbers, some positive and some negative. Square these to give 11 positive numbers. Add them up. Divide by 11. That what you mean?

Comment: I easily found the variance. Let me show you the original question....

Comment: The range is not required here. One standard deviation either side of the mean is 78 - 18.38 to 78 + 18.38. Now count how many values are in that range.

Comment: oh dang....oops. I put 65-18 instead of 78 -18

Comment: What does "what is between two standards of deviations of the mean" mean? I thought there was only one standard deviation...

Comment: Two standard deviations is just looking for the number of data values between 78 - 2(18.38) and 78 + 2(18.38). This range will capture most of the data usually.

Comment: Your method largely looks ok.  You don't need the max or the min or the range to find the standard deviation.  One potential danger is that many software packages will divide the sum of squares of deviations by $15-1=14$ rather than by $15$ to get the variance.  That should be done ONLY when ESTIMATING the variance of a population and the numbers you have are a sample from that population. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user296473 : It appears that what was meant was "within two standard deviations of the mean", but the reader was initially confused about the terminology. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, thank you. I really appreciate it!!!